# Google sheets script for setting values in a column

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets "Weights" and "Marks_All". I want to do the following:

1. read two variables `wt1` and `wt2` from "Weights"
2. read three columns `E`, `R` and `AM` (from row 4 to row 94; 90 values each in all three columns)
3. set values in column `AS` (from row 4 to row 94; 90 values) according to the formula

> (value in E[row]) + (value in R[row]) * `wt1` + (value in AM[row]) * `wt2`

The following code gives me an output, but is there a better method?

```
function Result () {
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Weight");
var wt1= sheet1.getRange("C4").getValue();
var wt2=sheet1.getRange("C10").getValue();
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Marks_All");
 for (var row = 4 ;row < 95; row++) {
      {
           var range1 = sheet2.getRange(row,5).getValue();
           var range2 = sheet2.getRange(row,18).getValue();
           var range3 = sheet2.getRange(row,39).getValue();
           var Result = range1+range2*wt1+range3*wt2;
           sheet2.getRange(row,45).setValue(Result);

      }
}
```

Comment: Are all the variables `range1`, `range2` and `range3` set and equal size?

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typo / OP didn't do any debugging at all: OP is setting the cell output to `undefined` because he writes the value from the empty array `T_W`, rather than the variable `result`. Furthermore, OP is doing math on arrays and not values - `range1` is `Array[][]`, so `range1[row]` is `[a value]` and not `a value`.

Comment: I have updated my code. I am getting the results. But I want to know if a better method exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- There are `Weight` and `Marks_All` in the same spreadsheet. So you can use each sheet by declaring `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` just once.
- Using `getValue()` and `setValue()` in the for loop is not efficient. So please use `getValues()` and `setValues()`.

  - In this modification, at first, the values of "A4:AM94" were retrieved.
  - The values were calculated.
  - The calculated values were put in "AS4:AS94".

#### Modified script :

```
function Result () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Weight");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Marks_All");
  var wt1 = sheet1.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var wt2 = sheet1.getRange("C10").getValue();

  var values = ss.getRange("A4:AM94").getValues(); // Modified: Retrieve values
  var results = values.map(function(e){return [e[4] + e[17] * wt1 + e[38] * wt2]}); // Modified: Calculate the retrieved values
  sheet2.getRange(4, 45, results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results); // Modified: Put the calculated values
}
```

#### References :

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works beautifully. Only one doubt though, doesn't indexing of columns start from 1 in sheets?

Comment: @user146297 Yes. The index of columns starts from 1. But the index of array starts from 0. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: OK. Thank you very much